# Adding comment with Excel VBA throws Application-defined or operation-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a comment with VBA to a cell in a worksheet.  I'm trying to do this for a number of cells so the comments have been loaded into an array.

I've (1) erased the array to start and (2) redim preserve the array and (3) filled the array.  All this looks good.

The 2 preceding lines work fine with another array:

```
Worksheets("Tree").Cells((vTreeRow(Y)), (vTreeCol(Y) + 1)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
Worksheets("Tree").Cells((vTreeRow(Y)), (vTreeCol(Y) + 1)) = Tree8(Y)
```

However, when my code executes this line, it throws the error

```
Worksheets("Tree").Cells((vTreeRow(Y)), (vTreeCol(Y) + 1)).AddComment vComm(Y)
```

I'm guessing that this issue is caused by something I don't know about arrays.  I've done some research but haven't found the answer yet

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

Comment: what's the vComm(Y) variable? Seems like there's code missing in this question.

Comment: Is there already a comment in the cell?  If so, you must delete the existing comment first with `Range.ClearComments`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `vComm` is a one dimensional array this will work:

```
With Worksheets("Tree").Cells(vTreeRow(Y), (vTreeCol(Y) + 1))
    If .Comment Is Nothing Then
        .Comment.Text Text:=vComm(Y)
    Else
        .AddComment vComm(Y)
    End If
End With
```

If `vComm` is a 2 dimensional array of values assigned from a column of data then use:

```
With Worksheets("Tree").Cells(vTreeRow(Y), (vTreeCol(Y) + 1))
    If .Comment Is Nothing Then
        .Comment.Text Text:=vComm(Y, 1)
    Else
        .AddComment vComm(Y, 1)
    End If
End With
```

It would be helpful if you included the `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`.

Comment: you meant Not .Comment Is Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

For testing:

1. Try to add sg else with addcomment, not the array (e.g. simple =Y) and see if it fails, and if yes, when.
2. Print Y and vComm(Y) into cells(), just to see where your code interrupts and why.

If you have already done it, tell us what is your experience.